# Inner angles of an irreducible graph on a sphere

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Given an irreducible graph on a ball (a sphere in three dimensions). The inner angles of a triangle, quadrangle and pentagon are smaller than $180^{\circ}$. Could anybody give a proof of this statement?

Answer (score 1):

If this is in relation to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/821655/35416), then it seems to me you're dealing with regular polygons, which are of course convex. Otherwise, it would be fairly easy to draw a non-convex quadrilateral on a sphere, where the inner angle at the non-convex corner would exceed $180°$.